# Looping through a Payload to get all pages

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I know you can loop through page numbers in a URL but is it possible loop through pages in a Payload? I would guess you need beautiful soup? At the end of the Payload, there is this code.

**page=1&start=0&limit=250**
Currently, I am just getting page 1 with 250 lines. I need to loop through the code and retrieve **page=2&start=251&limit=250** and the subsequent 11 pages. Could anyone show me how to do this?

**Working Code for first 250 Lines**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def stock_data(stock_info):
    data = pd.DataFrame(stock_info)
    data = data.iloc[:, 4:]
    data.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


url = "https://www.stockrover.com/stock_infos/grid?_dc=1644876887410"

payload = "state=%7B%22sortInfo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B76%2C77%2C50%2C80%2C547%2C13%2C21%2C771%5D%2C%22view%22%3A313%2C%22priorPrimaryColumn%22%3A170%2C%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22New%201%22%2C%22cType%22%3A%22Screener%22%2C%22cNode%22%3A%22s_42%22%2C%22cIsFolder%22%3Afalse%2C%22gridSelection%22%3A%22ANDE%22%2C%22lastActive%22%3A1396898415%2C%22primaryColumn%22%3A76%2C%22folderDisabledParams%22%3A%7B%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22mainGridDateRange%22%3A%22ytd%22%2C%22groupState%22%3Anull%2C%22moversGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22peersGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22lastGridSelections%22%3A%5B%22ANDE%22%5D%2C%22lastQuantNode%22%3A%5B%22s_42%22%2C%22s_42%22%5D%2C%22includeQuotesInTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22includeAllQuotesLastValue%22%3Afalse%2C%22markets%22%3A%7B%22panel%22%3A%22summary%22%7D%2C%22researchPanel%22%3A%22comparisonPanel%22%2C%22recentSearchTickers%22%3A%5B%22SPY%22%2C%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22s_32%22%2C%22%5ENDX%22%2C%22AXP%22%2C%22XOM%22%2C%22AFL%22%2C%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22AIT%22%2C%22ADVC%22%5D%2C%22quotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22checkedQuotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22dashboard%22%3A%7B%22buttonRef%22%3A%22272%22%7D%2C%22tickerSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Benzinga%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22marketSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Stock%20Market%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22bondsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Bonds%20Strategy%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22commoditiesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Commodities%20%26%20Futures%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Fundamental%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Strategy%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22stocksSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22CNNMoney%20News%22%2C%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Seeking%20Alpha%20Top%20Stories%22%5D%2C%22etfsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Economy%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22ETF%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Investing%20Ideas%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22topPanel%22%3A%22researchPanel%22%2C%22maxRecordsNode%22%3Afalse%2C%22version%22%3A7%2C%22lastGridSelectionsRaw%22%3A%5B%22ANDE%22%5D%2C%22lastSelectionScreeners%22%3A%22s_42%22%2C%22quotesDisabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22lastSelectionPortfolios%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22comparisonPanels%22%3A%7B%22Portfolio%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22Index%22%3A%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22Watchlist%22%3A%22Watchlists%22%2C%22Screener%22%3A%22s_42%22%7D%2C%22lastSelectionWatchlists%22%3A%22w_26%22%2C%22indicesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22newsActive%22%3A%22tickerNews%22%2C%22recentSearchMetrics%22%3A%5B%22Price%22%2C%22EPS%22%2C%22Sales%22%5D%2C%22editPanel%22%3A%22positionsPanel%22%2C%22newsType%22%3A%22marketNews%22%2C%22tableColumns%22%3A%5B%22ticker%22%2C%22rank%22%2C%22score_rank%22%2C%22filter_score%22%2C%22company%22%2C%22cash%22%2C%22currentassets%22%2C%22netppe%22%2C%22intangibles%22%2C%22totalassets%22%2C%22currentliabilities%22%2C%22longtermdebt%22%2C%22totaldebt%22%2C%22totalliabilities%22%2C%22equity%22%2C%22tangiblebookvalue%22%2C%22cash_short_term_p%22%2C%22net_ppe_p%22%2C%22intangibles_p%22%5D%2C%22last_save%22%3A1644837064%2C%22panels%22%3A%7B%22collapsed%22%3A%7B%22chp%22%3Atrue%2C%22ip%22%3Atrue%2C%22mp%22%3Afalse%2C%22qp%22%3Afalse%2C%22conp%22%3Atrue%2C%22fsp%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22viewportWidth%22%3A%221920%22%2C%22viewportHeight%22%3A%221069%22%2C%22chartPanelHeight%22%3A483%2C%22controlPanelWidth%22%3A296%2C%22insightPanelWidth%22%3A%22485%22%2C%22quoteBoxHeight%22%3A200%2C%22navigationPanelWidth%22%3A277%7D%7D&updateMarket=true&page=1&start=0&limit=250"

headers = {
  'authority': 'www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
  'x-csrf-token': 'fAeVScD26lby5MQf5YFI5p3snudo3E+rw0TL0h1W3j/vcjsIMvgxAF5Z9DkMjjCU4trT/b4EV0VCCPvmms5VIw==',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'origin': 'https://www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.stockrover.com/research/all/313/s_42/ANDE',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cookie': 'remember_me_pref=0; user_name=test11964; plan=3; premiumBraintreeKey=MIIBCgKCAQEAzM4LJfrNnBOgRFB1dDJkmqTFCWT2Y%2BksOydD8xDH4R033WUzxbffMZb%2B3dqEyQvOVjLcwFIHByDc4Xwej7enas2E%2FVRyh7Cvyadn7M5zQeRyLcI9Ys5KCozMwxJPc0x76FlXPwiAo1Qlz3RcLb9wGHBag2R51FuTie%2BhVDCgzWajqDCREzRhi%2Fqlt3D%2FxXNo%2FiwJlpOUr%2Fx1QnkkILxgKlq1dD7KJ767O5ojYKXsO%2BV2Bfu7sSD3djsOxQJ1%2FRbaDm2E96EDkWhhOeOpPndQ6IuSl4NmnJg%2Fcq6f8csW8M3Ys%2BMZPFkdxPC4%2FfRM1XC9o76PjpVNBIO%2ByJEELKZedwIDAQAB; lr=1644876886; _Ruby2_session=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%3D--b963330daa985315420ea5893f1cfa3e3a54c9d5; _Ruby2_session=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--a126f3bcc5b8af0a5a824e6b674d55f1fe9ee12e; lr=1644876939'
}

 
for page in range(3):
    pld = payload.format(page+1, page*250, 250)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=pld)
    stock_info = response.json()['stock_infos']
    stock_data(stock_info)
```

Comment: Right, you will have to use something like BeautifulSoup to fetch the URLs for the next pages, and then fetch each of those in turn.  You know the format for the URL, but you'll need to know when to stop.

Comment: It's not really a URL though that would change, it's the payload code that has to change, unless I'm misunderstanding which is likely.

Comment: Looks like it.  So, you can change the `payload` string to a template, like `...&page={}&start={}&limit={}"`.  Now you can do `pld = payload.format( 1, 0, 250 )`, and substitute the required valies for the later pages.

Comment: I can get any page data individually with your code, however I still don't know how to get multiple pages.  Can anyone help?

Comment: ??? You use a `for` loop to fetch 250 at a time.  1,0,250 then 2,250,250 then 3,500,250.

Comment: I certainly understand the concept but I just read a bunch of looping tutorials and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it in a loop.  This works; I've tried it here.

```
for page in range(3):
    pld = payload.format(page+1, page*250, 250)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=pld)
    stock_info = response.json()['stock_infos']
    stock_data(stock_info)
```

You will, of course, need to modify your code so that `stock_data` doesn't overwrite the CSV file every time.  You can either append to one big dataframe, or append to the CSV file.

Comment: I'm still only getting the first 250 results? I put the code I'm using in my original post. I tried it your code before headers and I get an error so I put it at the bottom. In your last comment are you saying the first 250 will be overwritten by the 2nd group of 250 and so on? Thanks

Comment: Yes, because your `stock_data` function writes the dataframe to CSV file, and each write destroys the last one.  I put `print(data)` in `stock_data`, and it was clearly moving forward through the pages.

Comment: Just confused why in the Csv, I’m still getting 1-250 instead of 500-750?

Comment: Because you changed your `payload` template and removed the format brackets.  Your payload needs to end `&page={}&start={}&limit={}"`.

Comment: Oh right, now it's working. Thanks for your time and patience. I'll look into how to append so I can get all the pages in one file.